# grails google.visualization.Map resize event

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, google-visualization

I'm struggling to find a solution on this issue:

I have the latest twitter bootstrap plugin with google visualization plugin latest but I cannot make the map package of the google visualization plugin to work corectly.
Indeed the map displayed is only a partial one, only a little square of the map is shown, the remainings is grayed out. I try to change the css style of the map image with 'max-width:none;' but it doesn't work.
When I resize the browser then the map get resize and display correctly.
I have found similar post but no answer that works for me.

The map is displayed in a tab of a twitter bootstrap modal window. 
I'm sure this has something to do with the resize so do you know how to trigger an event to resize the map? An is it even possible with google visualization map?

Thanks